# Advice in proving Big O complexities

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory

I am learning about complexity theory and have a question asking to show truth/falsehood of a number of Big-O statements.

I've done the first few e.g. showing 2^(n+1) is in O(2^n) by finding a constant and N value. But now they are asking more abstract things, for example:

If f(n) is O(g(n)), is log f(n) in O(log g(n))?

Is 2^(f(n)) in O(2^(g(n)))

These both seem like they would be true but I don't know how to express them formally with a constant and a N value. If you can give an example of how I could show these I can go do the rest of the problems.

Comment: The second example statement is wrong, try to think of counter-example to it. This question may be more appropriate for https://math.stackexchange.com, because it is not about any particular algorithm's time complexity, but rather about the Big-O notation in itself.

Comment: Actually, in mathematical sense, if we talk about arbitrary functions, the first statement is also wrong (e.g. when `f -> 0` and `log f -> -oo`).

Comment: @dyukha Yes, I didn't want to give a full answer. If `f` is allowed to decay to zero, then the first statement is wrong as well. For increasing functions, it does however hold.

Answer (score 0):

The comments are both accurate. Here are some notes along the lines you are probably looking for.

Assume f(n) is O(g(n)). Then there exist n0 and c such that f(n) <= c*g(n) for n >= n0. Take the logarithm of both sides. log(f(n)) <= log(c*g(n)). We can use the laws of logarithms to rewrite this as log(f(n)) <= log(c) + log(g(n)). If g(n) is greater than 1, then log(c) + log(g(n)) <= (1+log(c))*log(g(n)), so we can choose c' = 1 + log(c) and get the desired result. Otherwise, note that for g(n) = 1 we're still good since any choice for c' works.

The second one is not true. Choose f(n) = 2n and g(n) = n. We see f(n) is O(g(n)) by choosing c = 3. However, 2^(2n) = 4^n is not O(2^n). To see that, assume we had n0 and c. Then 4^n <= c*2^n. Dividing by 2^n gives 2^n <= c. But this can't be correct since n can increase indefinitely whereas c is fixed.